# Semantics For Quantifiers

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Good evening!

I have got a question concerning semantics with quantifiers.

We have a Syntax:

S = {$animal$: Type}

OP = $\emptyset$

REL = {

Is_dog: $animal \to Prop$

Needs_care: $animal \to Prop$

}

Variables: $X_{animal} = \{x\}$

And an expression:

$t_{1} =_{df} \forall x ($Is_dog($x$)$\to $Needs_care($x$)$)$

X-valuation is:

$ \beta_{1}(x) = 1 $

Semantic mappings:

Is_dog $ =_{df} \left\{\begin{array}{ll} \top \ if \ x \ is \ a \ dog \\
         \bot \ if \ x \ is \ no \ dog \end{array}\right. $

Needs_care $ =_{df} \left\{\begin{array}{ll} \top \ if \ x \ needs \ care \\
         \bot \ if \ x \ doesn't \ need \ care \end{array}\right. $

Now I wonder how to determine the value of $ [[t_{1}]]_{\beta_{1}} $.

Has anyone an idea?

Thanks

Comment: The sentence $t_1$ has no free variable $x$; thus, it truth-value does not depend on the valuation $\beta$.

Comment: The sentence says : "Every dog needs care". Is it true ? Maybe...

Comment: Having selected an interpretation $\mathfrak A$ with domain $A$, the *semantics* for an universally quantified sentence $\forall x \varphi(x)$ will be  : $[\forall x \varphi(x)]_{\mathfrak A} =_{def} \min \{ [\varphi(x)]_{\mathfrak A, \beta} \mid \beta (x) \in A \}$.